# Rejection and reapplying

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Can anyone tell me if it's possible for my friend to apply to Canada for student Visa, after he have got rejected in Japanese student Visa because the agent who have applied his visa have not given the correct financial document. Moreover nothing has been stamped on his passport saying that he is rejected. Should we mention about his rejection when he is applying again to Canada?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me if it's possible for my friend to apply to Canada
>   for student Visa, after he have got rejected in Japanese student Visa

Yes, it is possible to apply. His chance to get one, however, is lower than if he weren't denied before.

**Visa denials are very important**. They indicate that someone spent time evaluating the applicant's details and came to unfavorable conclusion. Thus the circumstances about rejection have to be carefully and truthfully addressed. Notably:

> because the agent who have applied his visa have not given the correct
>   financial document

would need more detailed explanation, including the rejection letter and a written explanation from an agent, if you have them. Please note that some Embassies share this information automatically, and an Embassy has an option to contact another Embassy to get more details about the particular case.

> Should we mention about his rejection when he is applying again to
>   Canada?

Yes, you should. There is a possibility they already share this information, or they may start sharing it later. If it was found out he lied about an important material fact (and prior denials is such fact), his visa would be retroactively canceled - possibly affecting his current status - and he possibly might end up being prosecuted. Some countries also permanently ban visitors for misrepresenting material facts in their visa application, even if their current circumstances no longer qualify for rejection.